# display assets image in listview

Tags: android, image, assets

I used this code but: The image is not getting displayed in my child activity. Please explain me in procedure how can i do .

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity2);

      Bundle fieldresults = this.getIntent().getExtras();
      String backgroundpath = fieldresults.getString("maps");
//      getResources().getAssets().openFd(fileName)
//    Drawable image = getResources().getAssets();
//    imageView.setImageDrawable(image);
      Bitmap background = null;
    try {
        background = getBitmap(backgroundpath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      ImageView gallerypic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
      gallerypic.setImageBitmap(background); 


private Bitmap getBitmap(String name) throws IOException

{
    AssetManager asset = getAssets();

    InputStream is = asset.open(name);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: What is the content of the variable backgroundpath ?

Comment: it gets the path of the image file that is in assets folder

Comment: I knew that but I think it should not be the path but only the image name. By the way, why not using a resource ID (as it's an asset) and load it with `getResources().getIdentifier(drawableName, "drawable", getPackageName());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2);
        ImageView gallerypic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        String backgroundpath = getIntent().getExtras().getString("maps");
        String backgroundextension = getIntent().getExtras().getString("extension");

        if(getImageFromAssert(backgroundpath,backgroundextension)!=null){
            gallerypic.setImageDrawable(getImageFromAssert(backgroundpath,backgroundextension));
        }
    }

    private Drawable getImageFromAssert(String name,String extension){
        try {
            InputStream ims = getAssets().open(name + "." + extension);
            return Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
        }catch (Throwable e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: @HareshChhelana Will it create OutOfMemory issue? I have try some of the way to load image from asset to listview but after some times it causes OutOfMemory issue.